# Google Tag Manager tag fires unintentionally from javascript setAttribute()

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a Form Submission event that fires on form submissions.

However, we have some custom javascript code that runs on page load, changing the value of the submit button. This triggers an unintentional form submission on page load. Here's the code:

```
 document.querySelectorAll('[data-showlabel]').forEach(item => {
    let showLabel = item.getAttribute('data-showlabel');
    item.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').setAttribute('value', showLabel);
  });
```

How could I fix this?

EDIT:
Here's the GTM trigger:
[image: GTM trigger]

Thanks

Comment: You need to show GTM setup for the trigger and the tag please

Comment: edited the OP, hopefully it helps. thanks